# Constructing motivic representations through extensions of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, anabelian-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$In the *Esquisse*, Grothendieck explains how to find the representations of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on Tate modules of Jacobians through its action on $\widehat{\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})}$.  This has already been discussed in this question: [abelian $\ell$-adic representations in $\widehat{SL(2,Z)}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190999/abelian-ell-adic-representations-in-widehatsl2-z?rq=1).

In a footnote to this passage, Grothendieck mentions a way to extend this idea $($here, $\Gamma = G_{\mathbb{Q}})$:

> In 1981 I began to experiment with this machine in a few specific cases, obtaining various remarkable representations of $\Gamma$ in groups $G(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$, where $G$ is a (not necessarily reductive) group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, starting from suitable homomorphisms $$\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow G_0(\mathbb{Z}),$$ where $G_0$ is a group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, and $G$ is constructed as an extension of $G_0$ by a suitable group scheme.  In the "tautological" case $G_0=\SL(2)_{\mathbb{Z}}$, we find for $G$ a remarkable extension of $\GL(2)_{\mathbb{Z}}$ by a torus of dimension 2, with a motivic representation which "covers" those associated to the class fields of the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(j)$ (as if by chance, the "fields of complex multiplication" of the two "anharmonic" elliptic curves).

I am interested in understanding what this means, even in the "tautological" case.  I can phrase the question as follows.

In general, how does one construct a representation (in this context not necessarily linear, e.g. an outer action) of a suitable extension?  That is, given an exact sequence of group schemes
$$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow \SL(2, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 1,$$
can one produce an action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $G(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ starting with an action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $\widehat{\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})}$?  Breaking it down:

1. Even in the trivial case of $N=1$, we have this object $\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ whose relation to $\widehat{\SL(2, \mathbb{Z})}$ is unclear to me.  Is it clear that the representation here is essentially the one we started with?
2. Assuming the first issue is resolved, which $N$ will naturally give an action on $G(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$?  Perhaps those who themselves carry some action of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$?  In any case, it seems that Grothendieck suggests that tori should be included.
3. What does it mean for a motivic representation to "cover" those associated to the class fields of the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(j)$?  It sounds like there is a separate concept of motivic representations of class fields (??) that I am ignorant of, and they can be realized as quotients of this newly constructed representation.
4. Why does Grothendieck say "a remarkable extension of $\GL(2)_{\mathbb{Z}}$" rather than "a remarkable extension of $\SL(2)_{\mathbb{Z}}$"?

Any insight into these questions, or explanations of better questions towards understanding this passage, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your first question, your use of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ is confusing, since in the rest of your post you seem to use $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ as a group, not a group scheme. If you really meant $SL(2,\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$, then the relation between that and $\widehat{SL(2,\mathbb{Z}))$ is that the latter surjects onto the former (by the universal property of profinite completions), the [kernel being free profinite of countable rank.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191330/what-is-the-intersection-of-all-congruence-subgroups-of-the-profinite-completion)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Interesting result.